# How can I view how much time each cell took to run in a Jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

After I select `run all`, `run all above`, or `run all below` in a Jupyter notebook, how can I view how much time each cell took to run?

My question is different from [Simple way to measure cell execution time in ipython notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32565829/395857) as I want the running times for all cells, not just one. I.e., if the notebook contains 10 cells I want 10 running times.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simple way to measure cell execution time in ipython notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32565829/simple-way-to-measure-cell-execution-time-in-ipython-notebook)

Comment: @vishes_shell Thanks. I want for all cells, not just one.

Answer (score 7):

Install and enable [ExecuteTime nbextension](https://github.com/ipython-contrib/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions/tree/master/src/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions/nbextensions/execute_time): "Display when each cell has been executed and how long it took".

Installation and configuration details are [here](https://jupyter-contrib-nbextensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/nbextensions/execute_time/readme.html).

Comment: Best answer, this extension is a must-have! :D

Answer (score 5):

I believe only by putting magic function [`%%time`](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/interactive/magics.html?highlight=time#magic-time)

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt yeap, in the beginning of each cell.