# What does '%% time' mean in python-3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

What does `%%time` mean in python? I am using python 3 and have some source code containing

```
%%time
```

Does this call the time module? or does it have another function?

Comment: Full code or at least a snippet would be ideal to give you more precice answers. Also: Have you tried running the code to see what it does?

Comment: isn't that iPython?

Comment: like here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32565829/simple-way-to-measure-cell-execution-time-in-ipython-notebook

Comment: Formatting changes.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

`%%time` is a magic command. It's a part of IPython.

`%%time` prints the *wall time for the entire cell* whereas `%time` gives you the time for first line only

Using `%%time` or `%time`  prints 2 values:

1. CPU Times
2. Wall Time

You can read more about it in the [documentation](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html?highlight=%25time#magic-time)

Comment: When I use %%time in the beginning of the cell and run the particular cell, I get only the Wall time and not the CPU time. Also, could you clarify if the wall times and cpu times are expected to change every execution (without changing the code)?

Comment: @bobthebuilder I didn't have the same problem. Also, for your 2nd question, your computer/server might be idle or busy from time to time, therefore the CPU times are expected to vary in each execution.