# How to correctly measure the execution time of a cell in jupyter?

Tags: python, time, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I have a code that looks like this:

```
%%time
import time
time.sleep(3)
```

When I executed this cell in the jupyter I got this output:

```
CPU times: user 791 µs, sys: 1.47 ms, total: 2.27 ms
Wall time: 3 s
```

My problem is that when I am putting `sleep(3)` shouldn't the total time be 3sec instead of 2.27ms.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simple way to measure cell execution time in ipython notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32565829/simple-way-to-measure-cell-execution-time-in-ipython-notebook)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
CPU times: user 791 µs, sys: 1.47 ms, total: 2.27 ms
Wall time: 3 s
```

`CPU times` shows the time you used your CPU.
`Wall time` shows the real time elapsed since the beginning of the cell. This is the time you are interested in.

Try the following to see the difference:

```py
%%time
time.sleep(3) #Assuming the time module was already imported
```

You never used your CPU, hence CPU Times is `0s`

Answer (score 3):

**Another way to calculate execution time**

You can use this code to calculate total execution time for multiple cells or entire code

```
from datetime import datetime 

start_time = datetime.now() 

import time
time.sleep(3) 

print('Time elapsed (hh:mm:ss.ms) {}'.format(datetime.now() - start_time))
```

output:

```
Time elapsed (hh:mm:ss.ms) 0:00:03.008139
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to use the jupyter extension [Execute Time](https://jupyter-contrib-nbextensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/nbextensions/execute_time/readme.html)

[image]

To install it, read the documentation or have a look to that post: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/50384459/3733974