# Total Jupyter notebook elapsed time

Tags: python, time, jupyter-notebook, elapsedtime

I've used the usefull hint described in [vForce's answer on "Simple way to measure cell execution time in ipython notebook"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50384459/13535575) to get each Notebook cell elapsed time.
But how can i get the total notebook elapsed time at the end of the "Run all"?

Answer (score 0):

```
import time

def elapsed_time(start, end):
    hours, rem = divmod(end-start, 3600)
    minutes, seconds = divmod(rem, 60)
    print("Elapsed Time: {:0>2}:{:0>2}:{:05.2f}"
                .format(int(hours),int(minutes),seconds))

#Test

#First cell of your notebook 
start = time.time()
# Anothers cells ...

#Two last line of Notebook
end = time.time()
elapsed_time(start, end)
```